# How to plot a confusion matrix using heatmaps in R?

Tags: r, heatmap, confusion-matrix

I have a confusion matrix such that:

```
  a b c d e f g h i j
a 5 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
c 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
d 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
e 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0
f 1 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
g 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
i 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
j 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

where the letters denote the class labels.

I just need to plot the confusion matrix. I searched a couple of tools. Heatmaps in R looks like what I need. As I don't know anything about R, it is really hard to do changes on the samples. If anybody could help me shortly how to draw, I will be really appreciated. Or any other suggestion rather than heatmaps are welcome as well. 
I know there is plenty of samples about this, but still I cannot manage to draw with my own data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Greg mentioned, `image` is probably the way to go:

```
z = c(5,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,
1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

z = matrix(z, ncol=10)
colnames(z) = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i", "j")
rownames(z) = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i", "j")

##To get the correct image plot rotation
##We need to flip the plot
image(z[,ncol(z):1], axes=FALSE)

##Add in the y-axis labels. Similar idea for x-axis.
axis(2, at = seq(0, 1, length=length(colnames(z))), labels=colnames(z))
```

You may also want to look at the `heatmap` function:

```
heatmap(t(z)[ncol(z):1,], Rowv=NA,
               Colv=NA, col = heat.colors(256))
```

Comment: Many thanks! And one more quick question how can I put the column and row names on the plot instead of values from 0 to 1?

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve a nice result using `ggplot2`, but for that you need a data.frame with 3 columns for x, y and the value to plot.

Using `gather` from the `tidyr` tool it is very easy to reformat your data:

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")

# Loading your example. Row names should get their own column (here `y`).
hm <- readr::read_delim("y a b c d e f g h i j
a 5 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
c 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
d 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
e 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0
f 1 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
g 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
i 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0", delim=" ")

# Gathering columns a to j
hm <- hm %>% gather(x, value, a:j)

# hm now looks like:
# # A tibble: 100 x 3
# y     x     value
# <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a     a         5
# 2 b     a         0
# 3 c     a         0
# 4 d     a         0
# 5 e     a         2
# # ... with 95 more rows
```

Perfect! Let's get plotting. the basic geom for heatmap with ggplot2 is `geom_tile` to which we'll provide aesthetic `x`, `y` and `fill`.

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(hm, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=value)) + geom_tile()
```

[image: First attempt at a heatmap]

OK not too bad but we can do much better. First we probably want to reverse the y axis. The trick is to provide x and y as factors with the levels ordered as we want them.

```
hm <- hm %>%
  mutate(x = factor(x), # alphabetical order by default
         y = factor(y, levels = rev(unique(y)))) # force reverse alphabetical order
```

Then I like the black & white theme `theme_bw()` which gets rid of the grey background. I also like to use a palette from `RColorBrewer` (with `direction = 1` to get the darker colors for higher values).

Since you're plotting the same thing on the `x` and `y` axis, you probably want equal axis scales: `coord_equal()` will give you a square plot.

```
ggplot(hm, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=value)) +
  geom_tile() + theme_bw() + coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="Greens", direction=1) 
# Other valid palettes: Reds, Blues, Spectral, RdYlBu (red-yellow-blue), ...
```

[image: A better heatmap]

The finishing touch: printing the values on top of the tiles and removing the legend since it is not longer useful. Obviously this is all optional but it gives you material to build from. Note `geom_text` inherits the `x` and `y` aesthetics since they were passed to `ggplot`.

```
ggplot(hm, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=value)) +
  geom_tile() + theme_bw() + coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="Greens", direction=1) +
  guides(fill=F) + # removing legend for `fill`
  labs(title = "Value distribution") + # using a title instead
  geom_text(aes(label=value), color="black") # printing values
```

[image: Final heatmap]

You could also pass `color="black"` to `geom_tile` to draw (black) lines around the tiles. A final plot with the `RdYlBu` color scheme (see `RColorBrewer::display.brewer.all()` for a list of available palettes).

[image: Showcasing more options]

Comment: @agenis I just ran everything without any errors. Maybe a bad copy/paste?

Comment: ok you're right, maybe it was the browser that broke the data copy/paste. anyway i delete my comment

Answer (score 1):

The `image` function in R will take a matrix and plot a regular grid with colors based on the values in the matrix.  You can set a lot of options, but just calling image with your matrix as the only argument will create a basic plot.  Sounds like that would be a good place to start.

Comment: Yes, it works, and very simple as you said as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: Image can also plot a rectilinear grid

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `image` function suggested in another answer cannot be used as such because it reverses (mirror) the data, so you'll get it the wrong way. With a little transform you can coin a function that will plot it right:

```
set.seed(1)
d = data.frame(Y_label=rpois(100,1), pred=rpois(100,1))
Show = function(df, ...) {image(t(df[nrow(df):1,]), ...)}
Show(table(d), main="my confusion matrix")
```

[image]

Next step you can add some axis labels, customize it, etc.